# react with _socketobject address in memory

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to access socket objects from memory address "socket._socketobject object at 0x7f4c39d78b40" and use it for another function at different times. The clients are connected to port 9999 and I want the server to react with each one at a later stage while keeping the connection up.

```
def sock_con(host,port):
    host = host
    port = port
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, address = sock.accept()
        print client
        print type(client)
        print "Server (%s, %s) connected" % address
        mongoconn = connectionx('IP_Clients')
        key = {'addresses':'192.168.11.1'}
        data = {'client':str(client), 'addresses':address}
        mongoconn.update(key, data)
        client.settimeout(60)
```

The next code is at a different module which can be used at anytime:

```
import os,sys
import socket
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
from mgodb import connectionx
mongoconn = connectionx('IP_Clients')
x= mongoconn.find_one({'addresses':'192.168.11.1'})
client= eval(x['client'])


def send_stuff(client,addresses,arg1):
    while True:
        try:
            #data = client.recv(size)
            print data
            client.send(arg1)
            return data

        except:
            #raise error('Client disconnected')
            client.close()
            return False



send_stuff(client,x['addresses'],'test10')
```

Comment: Are those two different processes or two modules imported in the same process? I mean, are you trying IPC to transfer a socket from one process to another or just to store opened connection to use it later in the same process?

Comment: they are two different modules. Yes I  need to store open connection to use it later in the same process or a different one if  possible.why I'm doing this? it is because I'm using UI and this UI should interact with each client individually at different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use sockets later in the same process, just store them at their arrival and find them later. Something like this:

```
...
clients = {}
while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    clients[addr[0]] = client
```

So, if you stop the listening loop, or run it in a thread, or you run something else in a thread (doesn't matter), you can get the opened socket object from dictionary clients by the client's IP address.

```
client = clients.get("192.168.1.1")
```

But you should count in the port as well for detection, because there may be two different clients contacting you from same IP address.

If you want to send an opened socket to another process, well, it is doable but not worth the trouble.
You would need to send the socket's filedescriptor ( socket.fileno() ) to another process, and that can be done using Python module sendfds. It can be found on pypi.python.org.
Then, in receiving process, you would have to construct the socket wrapper object around it manually or trick somehow the existing _socket.dll/.so and socket.py modules to do it for you.
A lot of work and success dubious. What you should do instead is to use the dictionary to store sockets and create an interface (over socket, PIPE or whatever IPC) to forward messages to and from needed connected sockets.

Finally, you do not have to worry about this mess at all, because Python has asyncore module.
It already does the socket storing into dictionary and other useful stuff. The thing is, you need to know what you want to achieve to be able to adequately tune the asyncore client handler. Set correct buffer sizes etc. etc. But asyncore is elegant and you can easily mix it with existing GUI event loop. asyncore and asynchat are often used when creating push servers or instant-messaging-like systems.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much. your answers serves my purposes.